# How to check whether the values are in Float using jUnit assertion?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am trying to automate an API. In response, I am getting float value for one of the keys. The value is dynamic so the only thing I want to assert is to check whether the value is a float number or not. How can we assert that via jUnit5 library?

Comment: Do you have a pojo, that is mapped against the JSON schema?

Comment: yes,  I do have it.

Comment: Then a JSON mapping exception would be thrown if the json value is not a float. Test this exception.

Comment: ok, so I don't need to assert anything then?

Comment: Ok, can you show your POJO and the Test if you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try to read the value as a float using `Float.valueOf()`, if it can't be interpreted as a float the function will throw an exception and the test will fail. Something like this:

```
@Test
public void isFloat() {
    // this will throw an exception
    Float.valueOf("definitely_not_a_float");
}
```